# WAS Liberty Docker Image Deployment Issue in Openshift

Tags: docker, openshift, websphere-liberty

Am able to deploy Liberty docker image in Local Docker container and can access Liberty server.

I pushed the liberty image to Minishift installed in my system ,but when am going to create docker container, am facing error as follows:

Is anyone tried this before, please share your view:

Log Trace:

```
unable to write 'random state'
mkdir: cannot create directory '/config/configDropins': Permission denied
/opt/ibm/docker/docker-server: line 32: 
/config/configDropins/defaults/keystore.xml: No such file or directory
JVMSHRC155E Error copying username into cache name
JVMSHRC686I Failed to startup shared class cache. Continue without 
using it as -Xshareclasses:nonfatal is specified
CWWKE0005E: The runtime environment could not be launched.
CWWKE0044E: There is no write permission for server directory 
/opt/ibm/wlp/output/defaultServer
```

Comment: What does your docker file look like? The error messages indicate the user id launching the server lacks sufficient authority to write to the server output directory. I’ve only seen this in a Docker file written to run as a non-root user. The default liberty image runs as root.

Comment: OpenShift by default doesn't run your image as ``root``, so images expecting to run as ``root`` usually will not work.

Answer (score 2):

By default OpenShift will run images as an assigned user ID unique to a project. Many available images have been written so that they can only be run as `root`, even though they have no requirement to run as `root`.

If you try and run such an image, because directories/files have been set up so they are only writable by the `root` user, running the image as a non `root` user ID will cause it to fail.

Best practice is to write images so that can be run as an arbitrary user ID. Unfortunately very few people do this, with the result that their images cannot be used in more secure multi tenant environments for deploying applications in containers.

OpenShift documentation provides guidelines on how to implement images so that can run in such more secure environments. See section 'Support Arbitrary User IDs' in:

- https://docs.openshift.org/latest/creating_images/guidelines.html

If the image is built by a third party and they show no interest in making the changes to their image so works in secure multi tenant environments, you have a few options.

The first is to create a derived image which in the steps to build it, goes back and fixes permissions on the directories and files so can be used. Note that in doing this you have to be careful what you change permissions on, as changing permissions on files in a derived image caused a complete copy of the file to be made. If files are large, this will start to blow out your image size.

The second is if you are admin on the OpenShift cluster, you can relax security on the cluster for the service account the image is run as so that it is allowed to run the container as `root`. You should avoid doing this if possible, especially with third party images which you do not trust. For details on how to do this see:

- https://docs.openshift.org/latest/admin_guide/manage_scc.html#enable-images-to-run-with-user-in-the-dockerfile

A final way that might be able to be used with some images if total size of what needs to have permissions fixed is small, is to use an init container to make a copy of the directories that need write access to an `emptyDir` volume. Then in the main container mount that `emptyDir` volume on top of the directory copied. This avoids needing to modify the image or enable `anyuid`. The amount of space available in `emptyDir` volumes may not be enough if have to copy application binaries as well. This is probably only going to work where the application wants to update config files or create lock files. You wouldn't be able to use this if the same directory is used for large amounts of transient file system data such as cache database or logs.